# How to download a file from remote server to a remote server using cURL?

Tags: http, curl, ftp, libcurl, libssl

I have a system, Having 2 separate boards running Linux on it, Connected to each other over IP. The main board is connected to the Internet but the other/slave board can not connect to the internet. Slave board is running a FTP server which is accessible to main board.

There is one file on Internet server/Cloud for the slave board, which I want to download directly on Slave board storage. So I need a mechanism on the main board, which will download the file from the Internet & transfer/stream it directly on the SlaveBoard FTP in chunks. I can not download entire file on main board & at the end transfer to slave board as I don't have enough space on the main board to store entire file on its local storage.

[Edit] Main board will act as moderator.

How to achieve this using Curl APIs in C application? Is there any mechanism already available to achieve this?
Will appreciate any lead in this.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I would have used NFS share or RSYNC sharing from slave board
where I have storage.

Prefer NFS over RSYNC but as per your use case , resources and expertise choose.

1. NFS server.
   create NFS server on slave board.
   mount that share on main board and download in this share.
   those downloaded files will be stored on slave board.
2. RSYNC
   another option install rsync on both machine

   rsync -rt rsync://root@x.x.x.x:873/files/ /home/pulledfromdaemon

once copy is successful you can delete files in main board.

don't use --delete flag which removes files when deleted from source.

Comment: Thanks @Devidas. I think RSYNC will download entire file on local storage on main board, which we can not as we don't have enough space on main board. Pls correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: Can we have streaming kind of mechanism on main board using curl & ssl? Where the file will be downloaded & transferred chunks directly on the slave board.

Comment: What about NFS ?

Comment: Can't setup NFS due to few limitations? Any other way?

Comment: you are correct about RSYNC. but you can delete files after sync. will be bit complex but doable hence I mentioned RSYNC. download file on main, you can pass md5sum (or sha256sum) check md5sum on slave. when sync is complete, you can trigger delete on main board.

Comment: I understood that but as I said for that I will need that much free space on the main board storage where entire file can be stored. you are right we can delete it once it gets synced. But at the first place only I don;t have that much enough free space to download the file. If I would have that much space available I could have used other methods of file transfer(SCP, Curlupload) once the file download is completed.

Comment: OK. NFS will solve your problem. As you will be using SLAVE's memory. Use slave machine as NFS server. mount that share on main board. you can access these files from SLAVE. also it won't need any memory on MAIN machine.